# UnboundLocalError, local variable accessed before assignment, but not?

Tags: python, django

I'm doing something pretty simple in Django and I'm getting this really weird error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /me/profile/edit/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment
```

Here's my code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print "Yes"
else:
    form = MyForm(user=request.user)
```

Why is this code throwing that error? It's pretty straightforward, yet if I take out the `if form.is_valid()` stuff, it works. What's going wrong?

Comment: Could you post the entire view function?

Comment: Post the code and the traceback as they appear.

Comment: My only guess for a situation like this is that you have spaces and tabs mixed up. 

I'm going to guess the `form.is_valid()` is actually indented to the same level as the first `if` statement. Common when copy and pasting...

Comment: I'm using spaces, not tabs :(

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to this problem is to remove the else clause:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None)

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        print 'Yes'
```

Danny Greenfeld's Advanced Django Form Usage presentation is a great example of this: http://www.slideshare.net/pydanny/advanced-django-forms-usage (slide 33 is what I'm referencing specifically).

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Note that the author you reference actually does `request.POST or None`. If you pass an empty dictionary to a form it will trigger form validation when rendering.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected the error.

Comment: Ah! I was confused and had to check it out. Otherwise that's a pretty cool trick. Thanks for sharing :)